# protecting PHP code from theft & reselling

Tags: php

I've written a PHP code I would like to sell.
I want to prevent other PHP programmers from buying the code and than reselling it as their own. (it happens)
I might even let others download the code for free, but still don't want those others to upload it to their sites and presenting it as theirs.

I was wondering if there is a way to hide the code from someone who gets a hold of it by somehow converting it to binary or byte code so that whoever downloads it from my site won't able to view the actual code or change it.
I mean without requiring the one running the PHP code to install on it's server.

I've seen threads about this from 2011 and 2014 (that didn't have solutions without bugs and do not support PHP7) and wondered if there is anything new in 2017...

Comment: To be honest your main recourse for this is legal rather than technical. You could maybe implement some sort of licence key activation system that limits it to approved domains but your primary means of enforcing this would be through a licence agreement.

Comment: "a PHP code" → does not sound overly valueable to begin with. Keep in mind to clearly advertise obfuscated code as such. There's enough low-quality scripts floating around already.